# Plan to execute choice of test cases from jmeter script using keywords

Tags: java, json, jmeter, keyword, beanshell

They are 40 test cases, so i plan to execute single test by using Keywords(testcases name). I prepared csv with 40 test cases name and called using CSV data config. And in mention call the keywords in User defined variables.

[image]

But while executing it was executing all test cases.

Comment: Can you give example of how your test case defined?

Comment: For example , my test was designed like,

**test case 1** ,
**test case 2** ,
**test case 3**

But normally while we are executing it will execute all test cases, but i want to execute only **test cases 2** now. So by using keywords we can executed **test case 2**. If other idea please let me know

Comment: But is test case a thread group/controller/sampler/file? it's not clear

Comment: yes, Each test cases are separate thread Group.

Testcase  1 - Thread Group, Test cases 2 - Thread group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below one it's working fine, Thank you for your suggestion's team :)

If you have 83 thread groups, then you could set something like this: (1) Put variable names like ${group01_threads} .. ${group83_threads} in all fields "Number of Threads (users)" of your thread group properties. (2) Then you need to create a CSV file ("threads-per-group.csv") with 83 lines like this to assign numbers of threads to each thread group (5 and 10 in this example): "group01_threads,5" .. "group83_threads,10". (3) Then, in your test plan, at the top, add a Config Element of type *** "jp@gc - Variable From CSV File" *** and let it read the "threads-per-group.csv". This way, you can create different CSV files with different mixes of threads per group as to define "load profiles" that you can include in your tests by command line parameter. If you define a line like "groupXX_threads,0", the thread group is just excluded from the test plan execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create jmx per test case, each will have a [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) with the flow and then use a general jmx where you send all the test cases in property and check each test case and if exists add [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) to include the relevant jmx

- Notice that you can't put variable/function in [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller). you must set the file name.

Answer (score 0):

1. For simple scenario you can use i.e. [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller), JMeter will execute only the sampler which name matches current variable from the CSV Data Set Config.
2. For more complex scenarios you might want to go for [Data Driven Test Design](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test), in this case we will need to know the format of your CSV file and the outline of the Test Plan.

Comment: Above will not use for my requirement, I have 40 test case in one script. So instead of executing all the test cases, i have to execute any one of the test cases by using keywords.